# Docusaurus v2 set security headers

Tags: javascript, security, header, docusaurus

In [Docusaurus v2](https://docusaurus.io/) I want to implement some security headers. But I couldn't find any documentation about security headers in Docusaurus.
Here are some header I want to add, especially to prevent other embed my docusaurus web as iframe.

```
 headers: [
                {
                    key: 'X-XSS-Protection',
                    value: '1; mode=block',
                },
                {
                    key: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
                    value: 'nosniff',
                },
                {
                    key: 'X-Download-Options',
                    value: 'noopen',
                },
                {
                    key: 'Cache-Control',
                    value: 'no-store',
                },
                {
                    key: 'X-Frame-Options',
                    value: 'SAMEORIGIN',
                },
            ],
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This is going to depend on how you're deploying docusaurus, since the headers should be returned by your web server

Answer (score -1):

If using express Application, you can do as follows -

To do this, you can modify your Express server configuration in the docusaurus.config.js file as follows:

- Edit the docusaurus.config.js File:

Open the docusaurus.config.js file in the root directory of your Docusaurus project.

- Install Dependencies (if not already installed)

Ensure that you have the helmet middleware installed as mentioned in the previous response.

```
npm install helmet
# or
yarn add helmet
```

- Use Helmet Middleware with Custom Security Headers:

Configure the Helmet middleware to include your custom security headers. Here's an example of how to add the headers you've mentioned:

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const app = express();

// Enable Helmet middleware with custom security headers
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", 'trusted-cdn.com'],
        // Add more CSP directives as needed
      },
    },
    // Add your custom headers here
    // For example, X-XSS-Protection, X-Content-Type-Options, etc.
    // You can add more headers following the same pattern
    // as shown below:
    // customHeaders: [
    //   {
    //     key: 'X-XSS-Protection',
    //     value: '1; mode=block',
    //   },
    //   {
    //     key: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
    //     value: 'nosniff',
    //   },
    //   {
    //     key: 'X-Download-Options',
    //     value: 'noopen',
    //   },
    //   {
    //     key: 'Cache-Control',
    //     value: 'no-store',
    //   },
    //   {
    //     key: 'X-Frame-Options',
    //     value: 'SAMEORIGIN',
    //   },
    // ],
  })
);

// ... Rest of your Docusaurus configuration ...

// Start the Docusaurus server
module.exports = {
  // ...
  scripts: {
    start: 'node server.js', // Use your server file name here
    // ...
  },
};
```

Customize the customHeaders array within the helmet() configuration with the headers you want to add. The example you provided includes headers for XSS protection, content type options, download options, cache control, and frame options. Adjust them to your specific security requirements.

Start your Docusaurus application using the command you specified in the scripts section of your docusaurus.config.js file.

With these modifications, your Docusaurus application should include the custom security headers you've specified. This will help enhance the security of your application by mitigating various common web security vulnerabilities.

If you are not using express,then you can create an alternate application that will serve as a middleware between the two end points and that application will serve as a helper in adding the security headers for you.

Hope this helps.